# Convergence in probability of minimum random variables.

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $X_n$ (independent) have Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$.
Let $Z_n=\min\{X_1,X_2,...,X_n\} $.
Does $Z_n$ converge in probability to $0$?

My idea:
$P(|Z_n-0| \le \epsilon)=P(|\min\{X_1,X_2,...,X_n\}| \le \epsilon)=1- (P(|X_1| \ge \epsilon) \cdot  ... \cdot P(|X_n| \ge \epsilon))$

I think, that I am very close but I'm not sure how to finish it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $0 \leq p < 1$ (for $p=1$ the convergence towards 0 does not hold).

Since all $X_i$ have the same distribution,
$$
1- \mathbb P(|X_1| \ge \varepsilon) \times \dots \times  \mathbb P(|X_n| \ge \varepsilon) = 1- \mathbb P(|X_1| \ge \epsilon)^n
$$

For $0 < \varepsilon \leq 1$,
$$
\mathbb P(|X_1| \ge \varepsilon)^n = \mathbb P(|X_1| = 1)^n = p^n \longrightarrow 0.
$$
For $\varepsilon >1$ this probability is $0$.

Therefore, $\forall \varepsilon >0$, $\mathbb P ( \vert Z_n \vert \leq \varepsilon) \longrightarrow 1$.